# hadoop: different datanodes configuration in shared directory

Tags: hadoop, configuration, directory

I try to run hadoop in clustered server machines. 
But, problem is server machines uses shared directories, but file directories  are not  physically in one disk. So, I guess if I configure different datanode direcotry in each machine (slave), I can run hadoop without disk/storage bottleneck.

How do I configure datanode differently in each slave or 
How do I configure setup for master node to find hadoop that are installed in different directory in slave node  when starting namenode and datanodes using "start-dfs.sh" ?

Or, is there some fancy way for this environment?

Thanks!